# file upload persistent storage issue with dokku

Tags: file-upload, digital-ocean, meanjs, persistent-storage, dokku

I'm having an issue with storing images to a dokku module that is running on digital ocean.

I'm using

- meanjs 0.4.0
- angular-file-upload (for the upload)
- digital ocean droplet with Dokku 0.3.18 and ubuntu 14.04

What I did so far:

1. Implemented and tested the code locally - works fine
2. Deployed the code to digital ocean
3. Added a persistent storage via:

   ```
   dokku docker-options:add vnmean run "-v /home/dokku/vnmean/share:/modules/pictures/client/img"
   dokku docker-options:add vnmean deploy "-v /home/dokku/vnmean/share:/modules/pictures/client/img"
   ```
4. Rebuild the app "dokku ps:rebuild vnmean" and checked the container via

   ```
   docker inspect <containerId>
   ```

With the result (at the end):

```
"Volumes": {
    "/modules/pictures/client/img": "/home/dokku/vnmean/share"
},
"VolumesRW": {
    "/modules/pictures/client/img": true
}
```

5. I also checked the two folders via:

   ```
   dokku run vnmean ls /modules/pictures/client/img
   ```

And via:

```
    ls /home/dokku/vnmean/share
```

I can change any of the folders via host-shell and the other one gets updated.

**Issue:**

Whenever I upload a picture via web-fileupload none of the folders is updated. I would expect that the `/home/dokku/vnmean/share` folder would now hold the uploaded data, but unfortunately it's unchanged.

I know that the picture upload worked as it is displayed afterwards but as soon as I do a restart or redeploy, the pictures are gone.

I'm not sure if I got something wrong with the persistent storage or if I missed a step.

Could you have a look and let me know what's the issue or what can be done to get a folder that stores the uploads without getting overwritten during restart or deploy and that can be accessed from the host-shell?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to set the owner of the folder

```
chown dokku:dokku /home/dokku/vnmean/share
```

Comment: The [docker-options portion](http://dokku.viewdocs.io/dokku/docker-options/) in dokku docs seems relevant. Key aspects are: dokku version, the two options commands and shared folder ownership.

Answer (score 0):

Dokku has a `volume` (Storage) -plugin since a while that abstracts some of the lifting.

http://dokku.viewdocs.io/dokku/advanced-usage/persistent-storage/